# Unable to push my flask-docker code to aws eb

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I keep getting this error when i try to deploy to aws eb::

```
Creating application version archive "app-6c68-230807_154922".
Uploading qube-flask-app/app-6c68-230807_154922.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
2023-08-07 20:49:24    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2023-08-07 20:49:29    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2023-08-07 20:49:32    ERROR   Instance deployment: Both 'Dockerfile' and 'Dockerrun.aws.json' are missing in your source bundle. Include at least one of them. The deployment failed.
2023-08-07 20:49:32    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2023-08-07 20:49:35    ERROR   [Instance: i-0d86da861e1f288e2] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2023-08-07 20:49:35    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2023-08-07 20:49:35    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0d86da861e1f288e2'. Aborting the operation.
```

Im not sure why I am getting this error because I have both "dockerfile" and "Dockerrun.aws.json.

I tried deploying using the CLI and got this error.

I tried zipping the file and deploying it manually and got a little bit of success but it still does not work.

I put all my eb-engine.log here:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1m05kjRuOIA_j7GOhkW7cNtUMowxXaXaLASOCsNOMmD0/edit

this is my dockerfile ::

```
# Use the official Python image as a base image
FROM python:3.9

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements.txt file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install the required Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Expose the port that your Flask app will run on (default is usually 5000)
EXPOSE 5000

# Command to start the Flask app with a volume mount
CMD ["python", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

this is the Dockerrun.aws.json file::

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
      "Name": "577826555055.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/qube-flask-app-dev:latest",
      "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
      {
        "ContainerPort": 80
      }
    ]
  }
```

not sure what the issue is, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is your file name `dockerfile` or `Dockerfile`?

Comment: dockerfile @jordanm

Comment: Need to rename to `Dockerfile`. It's case sensitive.